# Refine search results

Tags: xml, rest, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint rest search API.

I am asking it to return me a specific set of results.

It currently searches against a field called myfield. myfield is a multiple choice field. I am searching to return results where myfield equals a. It returns a result if it contains a (myfield = a;b;c) and if it equals only a (myfield = a).

However, I want it to return results where it equals only a. So not to return results if it equals a, but also others.

The query I am currently using is:

```
http://testurl.com/Sites/mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='(Country:FRA)(ContentType:mycontenttype)(myfield:a)'&rowlimit=50&SelectProperties='Title,LastModifiedTime,myfield'&trimduplicates=false&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'
```

I have tried to select refinement filters to no avail:

```
http://testurl.com/Sites/mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='(Country:FRA)(ContentType:mycontenttype)(myfield:a)'&rowlimit=50&SelectProperties='Title,LastModifiedTime,myfield'&trimduplicates=false&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'&refinementfilters='myfield:equals("AMER")'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using KQL? It seems as if you can use the "=" opeartion instead of ":".

```
":"
Returns results where the value specified in the property restriction is equal to the property value that is stored in the Property Store database, or matches individual terms in the property value that is stored in the full-text index.


"="
Returns search results where the property value is equal to the value specified in the property restriction.
Note
We do not recommend combining the = operator together with asterisk (*) when you do exact matching.
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx